# enable a set of textboxes using a button in html

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have managed to disable a set of text boxes using "disabled" tag. but I want all the text boxes enabled using a on-click in button. I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#btnSaveGenInfo').click(function(){
     $('#textfieldToClose').prop('disabled', false)
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should re-enable all text fields:

```
 $('input[type="text"]').prop('disabled', false);
```

Hope that helps!

EDIT

The submit button should look like this:

```
<button class="go-btn" type="submit">
```

Then the javascript can look like this:

```
$('.go-btn').click(function() {
    $('input[type="text"]').prop('disabled', false);
});​
```

Comment: so what should i put in button  <input button = "submit" onclick="??? "/>

Comment: Edited my answer to show you a button and then the code you could put in your javascript.

Comment: Did it work ok for you?

Answer (score 0):

try below code.  input[type="text"] contain all input which have type text . check working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/jqp8odoa/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#btnSaveGenInfo').click(function(){
    $('input[type="text"]').prop('disabled', false);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your could should be working. But through the fact you mention

> a set of textfields

and you are using the id-selector for referencing your textfield I would assume that you have multiple IDs in your document. See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) for the ID- and Class-specification.

Try the class-selector instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('#btnSaveGenInfo').click(function () {    
        $('.textfieldToClose').prop('disabled', false);    
    });    
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/j2fw22xs/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have duplicate IDs for textboxes. IDs should be always unique. You can rather assign common class(say `textfieldToClose`) to them and then use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#btnSaveGenInfo').click(function () {
  $('.textfieldToClose').prop('disabled',false);
});});
```